# django unique relations not unique table

Tags: python, django, django-models, unique

Take the following model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    #...
```

so what this does is connect a `Foo` model to a `Bar` model and each `Foo` model has a `name`.

**How can I make it so the name is only unique with respect to the connected `Bar` model??**

note: `unique=True` wont work because the name does not need to be unique throughout the entire table, it's just that there cannot be duplicate names in a specific `Bar` instance

## example:

lets say that `a` and `b` are instances of `Bar`

```
#the following is allowed
c = Foo(bar = a, name="foobar",...)
d = Foo(bar = b, name="foobar",...)
e = Foo(bar = b, name="barfoo",...)
#the following would not be allowed because
#an instance already exists in `a` with the name "foobar"
f = Foo(bar = a, name="foobar",...)
```

Comment: Add your own validation for that field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you talk about this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (('bar', 'name'),)
```

Comment: can you do this with a foreign key relation to compare a table and a value? If so this is correct